# How to troubleshoot: undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to …`

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I have read the flowing question and the answer, but I don't solved my problem.

[How to troubleshoot: undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148380/how-to-troubleshoot-undefined-reference-to-non-virtual-thunk-to)

I build code::blocks with mingw32 on windows.
I get the error on the link step, this is my link command:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Lbase/tinyxml -LC:/wxWidgets-3.1.1/lib/gcc_dll -Ldevel31 -Lexchndl/win32/lib -o devel31/codeblocks.exe .objs31/src/app.o .objs31/src/appglobals.o .objs31/src/associations.o .objs31/src/backtracedlg.o .objs31/src/breakpointsdlg.o .objs31/src/compilersettingsdlg.o .objs31/src/cpuregistersdlg.o .objs31/src/crashhandler.o .objs31/src/debugger_interface_creator.o .objs31/src/debuggermenu.o .objs31/src/debuggersettingscommonpanel.o .objs31/src/debuggersettingsdlg.o .objs31/src/debuggersettingspanel.o .objs31/src/disassemblydlg.o .objs31/src/dlgabout.o .objs31/src/dlgaboutplugin.o .objs31/src/editkeywordsdlg.o .objs31/src/editorconfigurationdlg.o .objs31/src/environmentsettingsdlg.o .objs31/src/examinememorydlg.o .objs31/src/find_replace.o .objs31/src/goto_file.o .objs31/src/infopane.o .objs31/src/main.o .objs31/src/notebookstyles.o .objs31/src/printdlg.o .objs31/src/projectdepsdlg.o .objs31/src/projectmanagerui.o .objs31/src/projectoptionsdlg.o .objs31/src/recentitemslist.o .objs31/src/scriptconsole.o .objs31/src/scriptingsettingsdlg.o .objs31/src/splashscreen.o .objs31/src/startherepage.o .objs31/src/switcherdlg.o .objs31/src/threadsdlg.o .objs31/src/virtualbuildtargetsdlg.o .objs31/src/watchesdlg.o  .objs31/src/resources/resources.res -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--no-undefined -m32  -lcodeblocks -lexchndl -lshfolder -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lcomctl32 -lodbc32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lwsock32 -lwxmsw31u -mwindows
```

the link error message is:

```
.objs31/src/startherepage.o:startherepage.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV9MyHtmlWin[__ZTV9MyHtmlWin]+0x414): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to wxHtmlWindow::SetHTMLWindowTitle(wxString const&)'
.objs31/src/startherepage.o:startherepage.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV9MyHtmlWin[__ZTV9MyHtmlWin]+0x418): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to wxHtmlWindow::OnHTMLLinkClicked(wxHtmlLinkInfo const&)'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: .objs31/src/startherepage.o: bad reloc address 0x418 in section `.rdata$_ZTV9MyHtmlWin[__ZTV9MyHtmlWin]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I have check the symbols in the libwxmsw31u, it's OK:

```
$ nm -po libwxmsw31u.a | c++filt | grep wxHtmlWindow::SetHTMLWindowTitle
libwxmsw31u.a:d021618.o:00000000 T non-virtual thunk to wxHtmlWindow::SetHTMLWindowTitle(wxString const&)
libwxmsw31u.a:d002747.o:00000000 T wxHtmlWindow::SetHTMLWindowTitle(wxString const&)
```

So, I don't know what happened to my link process, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think maybe something wrong with the libwxmsw31u.a, so I wrote a simple test application to check if the library is OK. And the result is it works, the test app is OK, no link error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched many information about this error, and get some hints from this article(it's Chinese version):

https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/27121990

So, I recalled my steps to build the Code::Blocks, I found I have add a flag for another error link. The flag is:

```
_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

But, when I build the libwxmsw31u.a, I didn't add this flag.

So, I try to remove this flag for Code::Blocks, and then it's linked correct.

And I have got my own Code::Blocks!

But, I am still don't know why this flag can cause this link error.